# @ConfigurationProperties does not work when using classes in the @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

## application.yml

```
foo:
  name: hun
```

## FooConfigurationProperty

foo.name in application.yml is bound.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class FooConfigurationProperty {

    private String name;
    
}
```

For quick testing, the FooConfigurationProperty bean was added using the classes property.

## FooTest

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = FooConfigurationProperty.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    FooConfigurationProperty fooConfigurationProperty;

    @Test
    public void fooTest() {
        System.out.println(fooConfigurationProperty.getName());
    }
}
```

The above results are output null rather than hun.

Why is null output when classes have specified to use a specific bean?

Comment: is it placed in main folder or test folder?

Comment: You should not use both `@Component` and `@ConfigurationProperties` on the same class, and you need `@EnableConfigurationProperties` (which is included in `@SpringBootApplication`) on a configuration class to activate it.